# Time constructible, non-time constructible functions

Tags: functions, turing-machines

> A function T:N→N is time constructible if T(n)≥n and there is a Turing Machine M that computes the function x↦└T(|x|)┘ in time T(n). (└T(|x|)┘ denotes the binary representation of the number T(|x|).)

--Arora, Barak

I was going through the following [link](http://cl-informatik.uibk.ac.at/teaching/ss07/alth/ohp/week5-2x2.pdf).

But the statement about "f(n)=c, f(n)=n are not time-constructible"
I am heavily confused about this statement. As the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Examples) says that f(n)=
n is a time-constructible function.

Firstly how is f(n)=c a non-time constructible function and secondly is f(n)=n a time/non-time constructible function?